# Checkboxes in Google Fusion map suddenly acts strange

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

This Google Fusion map (sort of a template) with three checkboxes used to work fine some weeks ago. 
http://www.kaasogmulvad.dk/unv/fusion/skabeloner/template_checkbox.html

I haven’t changed anything in the code, but suddenly the checkboxes acts strange. 
When I unclick “Yellow”, everything disappears. When I unclick “Red”, the red and green dots disappears. The same when I unclick “Green”.
“All” seems to work though.

Can this be a temporary error, or has Google changed something that makes my map act this way? And can anyone help me fix it?

The table with the information about the icon markers:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=4793185

Comment: You are using the "old" query syntax.  Does it work better if you use the documented "new" syntax?

Comment: Seems like "IN" might be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. character encoding with the values in the column
2. you are using the same variable name (layer) for two different fusion tables (bad, not sure if this is the real problem)

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_skabeloner_checkboxB.html)

Comment: I see, that your example works. Great! I'm not sure what your bullet 1 means? BTW - am I supposed to close the question - or mark it as answered. Sorry - but it's only my second question here...

Comment: Yes, now I see. I appreciate your help. But I don't understand why it actually worked earlier. I hope the question is accepted the right way now.